# Как передать запинание и заикание на письме

Tags: пунктуация, дефис

Как правильно передать запинание (заикание) на письме, для этого существуют какие-либо нормы?

Например, испуганный человек говорит: "П-пощадите...".
Или же восклицает: "Н-наверное!"

В данном случае повторение согласных будет записываться через дефис?
Если букв будет не 2, а 3, по типу: "М-м-может быть...",
то нужно ли ставить дефис между каждым запинанием?

Answer (score 1):

На форуме Грамоты.ру редактор спрашивает коллег, как лучше передать на письме авторскую фразу:

[Как бы вы записали прерывающуюся речь пьяного? Пример: "Шал…лава! Ты кто, вообще, так…кая? Приц…цепилась!"](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5490) (варианты ответов интересные/полезные).

В нашем случае важен тип заикания, которое следует передать письменно.

Заикаться можно и по причине "добора воздуха" на слово (ряд слов), тогда отточие, как в процитированной речи пьяного,

и не можа/могучи произнести согласный, тогда на выбор - повтор знака или, желательней, дефисное написание:

*ппполлучай, бббалда;*

можно подглядеть, как заикался Фандорин (черездефисно):

> С утра до вечера п-поили кофеем и разговаривали исключительно
>   по-французски. Жил на положении гостя у видинского к-каймакама.

Дефисы можно и удвоить (утроить, но не более): *п-п-поили к-к-кофием*.

Если почитать тест о проблемах заикания на скрине, можно сделать выводы, как что лучше отображается на письме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]